# Convert PDF to WORD with bookmark and link using Aspose PDF 18.9.1

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, aspose, aspose.pdf

I'm trying to convert a file from a .pdf to .doc format,
i'm using this library Aspose PDF 18.9.1 with license and Java 8.
The PDF document has bookmarks and link, when I get the
transformation of the doc file, if i click on the bookmark
and on the link doens't run. This is my code:

```
// Load source PDF file
Document pdfDocument = new Document("example.pdf");
// Create DocSaveOptions object
DocSaveOptions saveOption = new DocSaveOptions();
// Set format DOC
saveOption.setFormat(DocSaveOptions.DocFormat.Doc);
// Save the resultant DOC file
pdfDocument.save("example.doc", saveOption);
```

Comment: Would you please share source and generated files via Google Drive, Dropbox etc. so that we may try to reproduce and investigate it in our environment.
**PS**: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @FarhanRaza thank you, this is the file shared with google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mxhyi7BUac-A0I8FhjyBam0mk3xJhU1R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for sharing the file. I am afraid it does not contain any bookmark or hyperlink, Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader is not displaying it either. Kindly elaborate the page number and hyperlink text while mentioning the bookmarks so that we may proceed to help you out.

Comment: So, at page 1 there is the bookmark on the right corner, you can see it's an 'i' with a circle. the hyperlink is situated at page 7, on the right corner there is alittle arrow. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing requested data and information.

We have investigated the document and have figured out that it does not contain any bookmark but hyperlinks that is local hyperlink on page number 1 and external hyperlink on page number 7. We have verified this with Adobe Acrobat as well as with Aspose.PDF for Java API using below code snippet:

```
Document document = new Document(dataDir + "example.pdf");
{
    System.out.println("Bookmarks Count: " + document.getOutlines().size());
    for (int eachPage = 1; eachPage <= document.getPages().size(); eachPage++)
    {
        Page page = document.getPages().get_Item(eachPage);   
        System.out.println("Page: " + page.getNumber() + "  Hyperlinks: " + page.getAnnotations().size());
    }
}
```

Therefore, we have been able to reproduce the problem with hyperlinks when shared PDF file is converted to DOC file. A ticket with ID **PDFJAVA-38126** has been logged in our issue management system for further investigation and resolution. We will update you as soon as this ticket will be resolved.

We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Ok, I will wait for you, but I have to forecast to update the version of the library

Comment: We will let you know as soon as some significant updates will be available.